# Angular Material 6: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined at MatHeaderRowDef table

Tags: angular, angular6

Tested with **Angular Material: 6.4.5** and **Angular Material: 6.4.3**
but facing this issue

[image]

I have implemented the exact same example provided on https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

### Code

.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" *ngIf="displayedColumns">
  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

.ts

```
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string
  position: number
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen' },
  { position: 2, name: 'Helium' },
  { position: 3, name: 'Lithium' },
  { position: 4, name: 'Beryllium' },
  { position: 5, name: 'Boron' },
  { position: 6, name: 'Carbon' },
  { position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen' },
  { position: 8, name: 'Oxygen' },
  { position: 9, name: 'Fluorine' },
  { position: 10, name: 'Neon' },
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {      
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code. There might be something that may be missing.

Comment: nothing changed, I have copied and pasted the code

Comment: have a look, added code to it

Comment: can you share your `app.module.ts` code

Comment: code updated, review please

Comment: code works fine for me. I think this has got to do something with your code in the `VersionComponent`. Can you share that component 'ts' and `html`

Comment: what is your `angular material version`, you tested on it?

Comment: I have included this in separate component and separate route, still same issue. Can you provide your code snippet in `stackblitz` so that I can compare where I am making mistake? Or provide `package.json` dependencies.

Comment: See this : https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-ih3u8b?file=src%2Fstyles.css

Comment: your code sample worked fine. Though your code was same as mine but with different packages' versions. So I updated all packages and then run but same result in failure. Now trying to test table in completely new project. Let's see what happens :D

Comment: You can also share your stackblitz with the dependencies that you are using and then we can check where the problem lies

Comment: I have tested with fresh project, got success. Couldn't understand where problem lies in my original project, deleted node_modules, updated all packages, disabled all components and used app.component for table testing in my original project but failed

Comment: Happens with everyone buddy. Sometimes starting again is the solution. Glad you succeeded.

Comment: Thanks for best wishes, stay blessed :)